# Python splinter(Selenium) issue clicking menu link with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium, splinter

I'm trying to click a link in a frame with Splinter.  When I try by id, name, text, xpath it says element does not exist.  I tried to get all elements, but it also said could not be found.

```
import splinter

executable_path = {'executable_path':'C:\\code\\chromedriver-2.29\\chromedriver'}
web1 = splinter.Browser('chrome', **executable_path)

url = ""
ipAddr = '192.168.168.168'
web1.visit('https://' + ipAddr + '/' + url)

with web1.get_iframe('outlookFrame') as iframe2:
            IDs = iframe2.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')
            for items in IDs:
                print items
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'
```

I tried running execute_script(), that didnt work either.  I've put many hours with different approaches, but I cant figure it out.

```
with web1.get_iframe('outlookFrame') as iframe2:
            javaScript = 'toggleTree("pnl10","usersStatusView.html");'
            web1.execute_script(javaScript)
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
```

This is the menu I am working with. I am trying to get splinter to open usersSettingsView.html.  I cant open it directly from url as it breaks the config process, I have to use the menu.  I am looking for a recommendation on best approach because clearly mine is no good.

```html
<div id="nav_head1" class="nav_group" style="display: block;">
<div id="nav_arrow"><a href="javascript:toggleTree('pnl10','usersStatusView.html');"><img src="arrow_down.gif" id="apnl10" alt="" width="8" border="0" height="10"></a></div>
<div id="nav_icon"><a href="javascript:toggleTree('pnl10','usersStatusView.html');"><img src="icon_users.gif" alt="" width="20" border="0" height="20"></a></div>
<div id="nav_head1_text"><a href="javascript:toggleTree('pnl10','usersStatusView.html');" class="nav_font_head1">
Users</a></div>
</div>
<div id="nav_head2" class="nav_item" style="display: block;"><div id="nav_head2_textbox"><a href="usersSettingsView.html" onclick="javascript:hiLight(this);" target="tabFrame" class="nav_sub_sett">Settings</a></div>
</div>
```

All thoughts are welcome!  Thanks.

Comment: Might be irrelevant but have you tried `find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[0].click()` ?

Comment: or `execute_script("document.getElementById('nav_error').click()")`?

Comment: Tom.  find_elements_by_tag_name got a similar error.  The execute_script did not throw an error.  It did not do anything to Chrome(using chromium driver) nor return any data in python, but maybe I can continue down that line and get somewhere.

Comment: Can you post how you set up your `webdriver`?

Comment: Done.  See top of post